# Load view controller from another controller

Tags: ios, swift, controller

I am using this code to load view controllers inside a container in ViewController without using any segue. 
Example:

```
let newViewController =self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FBViewController")
            newViewController!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.cycleFromViewController(oldViewController: self.currentViewController!, toViewController: newViewController!)
            self.currentViewController = newViewController
```

This code is working for any controller but in one case where i need to load a controller called FBViewController and in its ViewDidLoad i check if the user is logged, in case he is i want to load another controller instead of theFBViewController immediately. 
I tried this code inside the viewDidLoad of FBViewController:

```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userProfilePage")
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I tried calling a method in the main view controller to load the wanted view:

```
 let otherViewController: ViewController = ViewController()
            otherViewController.loggedIn()
```

Method:

```
func loggedIn(){
    let newViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userProfilePage")
    newViewController!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.cycleFromViewController(oldViewController: self.currentViewController!, toViewController: newViewController!)
    self.currentViewController = newViewController
}
```

None of them worked. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Your code part is not complete so can't understand. But make sure that when you try to present new controller you should be doing it in main thread. I don't know what is your goal but you can present new controller over other ViewController or if you are using navigation controller than push new controller.If possible give detail about your requirement and may be detailed code part to understand better.

Comment: @Premal i edited the description, hope its obvious now.

Comment: don't use that code in view did load, use it inside view did appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following inside MainViewController:

```
var newViewController : UIViewController
if loggedIn == true {
    newViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userProfilePage")
} else {
    newViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FBViewController")
}

newViewController!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.cycleFromViewController(oldViewController: self.currentViewController!, toViewController: newViewController!)
self.currentViewController = newViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have should work, just go to your storyboard and select the controller you want to call. Then make sure that under storyboard ID you have the same name that you are using to call it.